# portal_membership.getAuthenticatedUser, portal_state.member etc.. always return anonymous on View object's __init__ and publicTraversal

Tags: plone

I'm making a View with customized traversal. I want to traverse to next object dynamically base on current logged in user. But all method I know (portal_membership.getAuthenticatedUser, portal_state.member etc..) always return anonymous on View object's `__init__` and `publicTraversal`. The only case they return right is in object's `__call__`.

What should I do to make getAuthenticatedUser work on my case (either on view's `__init__` or `publicTraversal` call)?

Comment: What's wrong with doing it in the `__call__` method? It should work the same there. Take a look at the product https://github.com/collective/collective.routes/tree/master/collective/routes for hints on how to best do custom and dynamic traversal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Due to Zope's security model, the user is determined *after* traversal, because this information depends on the context of the published object.

You can only rely on `getAuthenticatedUser` when the object is being published; after traversal, authentication and authorization take place, and then publication, which in views means invoking the `__call__` method.

Because `publicTraversal` is called as part of the traversal stage, you cannot know the authenticated user in that method either. You'll have to re-think your view to not rely on the authenticated user being known during that stage.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation. I wanted to make a "home" namespace that route all user-related action into one static url, ie: site.com/home/* == site.com/Members/userid/*. Never thought it'll be problematic though.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do anything in the `__init__` of your browser:view mainly because you cannot be sure that all the environment has been set up. Notably in your case, you can solve your issue by using the same methods in the `__call__` method instead that in the `__init__`

Comment: The problem is I want to get this on ``publicTraversal`` call, not on ``__call__`` call, and I haven't yet found a way to do it.

Comment: Why do you need to get it on publicTraversal?